# cannot read property 'grass' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

Goal: the long array will have the values of `this.token.grass` in it.

```
module.exports = {
    render: function() {

    },
    keyDown: function(k) {

    },
    level: [
        [this.token./** Error Here **/grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass],
        [this.token.grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass],
        [this.token.grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass],
        [this.token.grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass],
        [this.token.grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass],
        [this.token.grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass],
        [this.token.grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass],
        [this.token.grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass],
        [this.token.grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass],
        [this.token.grass, this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass,this.token.grass]
    ],
    NonCollidable: "$$$NonCollidable\\Main",
    Collidable: "$$$Colldiable\\Main",
    token: {
        grass: {RenderToken: "\x1b[32m#\x1b[89m\x1b[0m", TokenType: this.NonCollidable}
    }
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'grass' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\#\Desktop\libraries\unnamed\main.js:10:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.pointer (C:\Users\#\Desktop\libraries\unnamed\context.js:4:76)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\#\Desktop\libraries\unnamed\io.js:13:25)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Honestly, I haven't tried anything. I thought that maybe `this` in that context was referring to the parent array, but I don't know how to fix that either.

The code is above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `level` a function and make it return an array. Note not using arrow function as `this` will be different inside an arrow function

```js
module.exports = {
  render: function() {},
  keyDown: function(k) {},
  token: {
    grass: {
      RenderToken: '\x1b[32m#\x1b[89m\x1b[0m',
      TokenType: this.NonCollidable
    }
  },
  level: function() {
    return [
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ],
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ],
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ],
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ],
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ],
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ],
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ],
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ],
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ],
      [
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass,
        this.token.grass
      ]
    ];
  },
  NonCollidable: '$$$NonCollidable\\Main',
  Collidable: '$$$Colldiable\\Main'
};
```

Comment: This works. I think all array elements will point to the same object here, just pointing out. @Obscuredツ

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your context will refer to the global object which is in most cases the `window` object. Have a look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this